# why does Node Client for Google Cloud Vision API does not take aspect ratio into account

Tags: node.js, google-vision

I am trying to use the Node Client for Google Cloud Vision API.
I manage to get crop hints on a remote image using :

```
const [result] = await clientVision.cropHints(`gs://mybucket/${image.name}`,  
{imageContext : {cropHintsParams : {aspectRatios : [1]}}});
```

But the aspect ratio is not been taken into account. I can change the value of aspectRatios to 1 or 4 or a float 1.33333, I get the same coordinates for my vertices. The default aspect ratio seem to be 1.77.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the rest api:

```
function getHints(aspect, path) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    axios.post('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {
        "requests": [
            {
                "image": {
                    "source": {
                        "gcsImageUri": `gs://myproject/${path}`
                    }
                },
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type": "CROP_HINTS"
                    }
                ],
                "imageContext": {
                    "cropHintsParams": {
                        "aspectRatios": [
                            aspect
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }).then((response) => {

        console.info(response.data['responses'])

        var vertices = response.data['responses'][0].cropHintsAnnotation.cropHints[0].boundingPoly.vertices;


        if (vertices[0].x == undefined) {
            vertices[0].x = 0
        }
        if (vertices[0].y == undefined) {
            vertices[0].y = 0
        }

        if (vertices[1].x == undefined) {
            vertices[1].x = 0
        }
        if (vertices[1].y == undefined) {
            vertices[1].y = 0
        }

        if (vertices[2].x == undefined) {
            vertices[2].x = 0
        }
        if (vertices[2].y == undefined) {
            vertices[2].y = 0
        }
        if (vertices[3].x == undefined) {
            vertices[3].x = 0
        }
        if (vertices[3].y == undefined) {
            vertices[3].y = 0
        }

        resolve(vertices)

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response)
    });


})
```

I use it so :

```
var hints = await getHints(1.777777778, path)
```